# Change cursor color of an Editext for below 3.0 version

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change the android's edittext cursor color.I have used `android:textCursorDrawable` property but it supports only API level 12 or above.but my project `minSDKVersion is 9` .So how can i change cursor color in `below API level 12`.