# Change cursor color in EditText for all API's

Tags: android

I have gone through the questions in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238450/set-edittext-cursor-color), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523494/change-the-color-of-the-cursor-of-an-edittext-in-android-across-all-the-sdk) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814373/change-cursor-color-of-an-editext-for-below-3-0-version) . I cannot find way to change the color of EditText cursor in API's **2.2< and  < 3.2**  .

Perhaps `android:textCursorDrawable` is only available for targets with API level 12 ( or 3.2 )